# llvm jit compile to binary

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, binary, llvm, jit

Is it possible somehow to write a compiler producing LLVM IR code which user will JIT compile and after compiling it in memory it would be written to disk as binary file?

The idea behind this scenario is that I dont want to compile LLVM IR code and let users to execute it immediately (with lower performance due to JIT compiling). But I want that when users execute this program second time it would be already compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is how to reuse code produced by JIT when generating native binaries? I doubt there is API to do this, but remembering how MC JIT works, it might be relatively easy to implement.

But from my POV it's better to jsut compile LLVM IR into native code on the second run.